# Why Windows 7 cant see adb device

Tags: android, usb, adb

I have LG Optimus GT540 with broken screen, want to see a screen on my PC to retrieve some data.

To do this I've installed Android-SDK, set in Windows 7 path to it, but `adb devices` is not showing my phone.

Device is connected over USB, when I do it I can hear sound in phone that indicates something.
USB debugging is turned on on my device.

I have installed with `android SDK Manager` following packets:
Android SDK Tools, Platform-tools, SDK Platform Android 1.6, Google APIs, Google USB Driver

Why I cant see it?

Comment: Have you installed LG drivers for your phone?

Comment: @RaghavSood - no, shall I? Where to do it? In SDK Manager? Windows 7 in System Manager shows my phone as a disc/storage with letter G:/ but cant access it.

Comment: You might have better luck asking at android.stackexchange.com

Comment: Search the LG sites for the appropriate driver for your phone, and install it to wherever the driver installer asks you to.

Comment: Shall it be states as "Mass USB storage device" & "LGE Android Platform USB Device"? That's what it shows when installed USB drivers from LG, and still have no device in my CMD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should install USB Drivers for you device. 
Check this link:
http://www.android-cellphones.org/lg-gt540-usb-driver-download.html

Comment: Cool! Ive also found http://www.lg.com/uk/support-mobile/lg-GT540#software_panel

Comment: Strange is that PC Suite sees my phone, but adb not